# Generic List method specifying type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In Java I can have a method declaration something like this:

```
<T> List<T> getList(final Class<T> objectClass, String whatever)
```

Which means that I specify the list return type by specifying the Class to the method.

```
List<Customer> customers = getList(Customer.class, "blah");
```

And if I don't specify the classes properly I get a compile time error. (which is what I'm looking for - I want the compiler to catch a mismatch).

```
List<String> customers = getList(Customer.class, "blah"); // will not compile
```

What's the equivalent of this in C#?
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in C# to have the compiler infer the generic type based on the return type.

In C#, you must specify T if the only differentiation is the return type:

```
List<Customer> customer = getList<Customer>("blah");
```

This method would be written as:

```
List<T> getList<T>(string whatever) { ... }
```

However, in C#, type inference is automatically handled if there is a parameter that takes a type of customer.  For example, you can have:

```
List<T> MakeList<T>(params T[] items) { ...}
```

Then call this as (without `<Customer>`):

```
 Customer one = GetCustomer(1);
 Customer two = GetCustomer(2);

 var customers = MakeList(one, two);
```

---

Edit in response to comment:

If you are going to be constructing a new "Customer" inside of your method, and want this to work on any type, you'll need a new constraint in place.  To have this:

```
List<Customer> customers = GetList<Customer>("blah");
```

You would need something like:

```
List<T> GetList<T>(string whatever) 
   where T : new() // This lets you construct it internally
{
     List<T> results = new List<T>();

     /// ...
     T newInstance = new T();

     results.Add(newInstance);
     return results;
}
```

That being said, if you're going to make a method like this, chances are you'll also want to have a constraint to an interface, so you can setup the object you create:

```
List<T> GetList<T>(string whatever) 
   where T : ISomeInterface, new()
```

This will let you use properties of `ISomeInterface` within the method, as well as limit it to only working with types that implement that interface.

Comment: So how in that method could I determine which type to instantiate to add to my list?

Comment: @Dan: I just edited - see if that answers your question... (it's always tricky with cross-language concepts, since they're not exactly the same in C# vs Java)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's just

```
List<T> GetList<T>(string whatever) { /* ... */ }
```

you can put a constraint on T like

```
List<T> GetList<T>(string whatever) 
 where T : class
{ /* ... */ }
```

if you want to constraint it to classes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<T> getList<T>(String whatever) {
.
.
.
.
}
```

This mandates that the caller specify the type of T while calling the method.

Comment: But in this context I can't reference T in the method body to know which type of Object to instantiate.

Comment: @Dan: that requirement wasn't mentioned in the question, as far as I can see. Perhaps you should edit it to reflect the question that you actually want to ask.

Comment: You can use typeof(T) in the method.

Answer (score 1):

> `<T> List<T> getList(final Class<T> objectClass, String whatever)`

to:

```
List<T> GetList<T>(string whatever)
```

> `List<Customer> customers = getList(Customer.class, "blah");`

to:

```
List<Customer> customers = GetList<Customer>("blah");
```

> `List<String> customers = getList(Customer.class, "blah");` // will not compile

to:

```
List<string> = GetList<Customer>("blah"); // will not compile too
```

The syntax of the both languages so close